# AAD in Azure API Management, avoid signup dialog

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management you can enable integration with AAD, by following the guidelines in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad

This part describes the sign in after setting up AAD integration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad#a-idlogintodevportalsign-in-to-the-developer-portal-by-using-an-azure-ad-account

In step 3 of of this part, the following is mentioned: 
"You might be prompted with a registration form if any additional information is required."

I don't want to bother my consumers with this dialog, but I can't find what 'additional information' is meant here.
The sign up dialog only shows email, first name and last name.

Anyone knows what information the registration process is missing, which leads to this dialog to show up?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to bother my consumers with this dialog, but I can't find what 'additional information' is meant here. The sign up dialog only shows email, first name and last name.

If you don't want to enable the registration process, you could delete `Username and password` 
provider from azure portal.

[image]

It will just use the Azure AD provider. then it will **not** prompted with a registration form.

[image]

**Updated:**

If I click sign up, I get the registation is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I indeed removed the Username and Password identity provider, leaving only the Azure Active Directory one. This still prompts the registration form after sign in, while the three email/first/last name fields are pre-populated. It's unclear why this signup dialog is triggered anyway. Do you have experience with this to work as expected?

Comment: `Do you have experience with this to work as expected?` Based on my test, it works for me. You could have a try to incognito window or another browser.

Comment: I get the same result using incognito or a different browser. In my scenario an on-prem AD is sync-ed to AAD. Maybe that's an issue somehow? However the fact that the signup dialog is pre-populated, doesn't make sense.

Comment: If i click the sign up, I get the registation is disabled. For more information, you could refer to the updated answer.

Comment: I too get the 'registration is disabled' message when I click the sign up button directly, but that's not the question. This sign up dialog is shown right after the sign in dialog. This also is mentioned in the documentation, but it's unclear why it is shown because the fields are pre-populated to no data seems missing or not found. Thanks for thinking along, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the Azure API Management product group, it became clear you cannot disable this dialog at the moment.
The documentation is mentioning the dialog is only prompted in a certain case, but that's is not accurate. The dialog will always be shown when you sign in on the developer portal, when the Azure API Management is integrated with AAD.